# Boundary removal: Auto cropping multiple images containing text with differing margin sizes

Tags: image-processing, crop

I'm looking to crop thousands of images that contain text that I'm ultimately hoping to feed to tesseract.  Unfortunately, there is a boundary on all the images that I would like to cut away before attempting to transcribe the text (the location of the boundary varies from image to image). An example of the boundary text that I would like to remove appears in the image below --- the black box contains lines of text that I would like to keep (it is blacked out in this case as it is sensitive data). [image: Example Image]

I would typically use mogrify to pre-process images, but in this case the shifting location prevents me from doing so.  Can someone suggest a quick and dirty  approach to cropping these images? I've reviewed approaches using Python's PIL, but have not found a solution (I have limited experience).

Comment: image-magick has command line tools to do this

Comment: hey @leppie, cool, yes, I've looked at image-magick, but the problem is that the position of the boundary  (the +'s) is not always fixed.  I used the `-trim` command initially, but guess I can apply a crop thereafter.  I'll just need to make sure that the page is always oriented correctly.  I will give that a try now.

Comment: Ok great, a combination of `-trim` and `-shave` works in most cases.  However, the boundary disappears off the top of the page sometimes (the scans are not perfect), and then this approach fails as shave may then cut into text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the unpredictable margin lengths I was forced to use template matching instead. The python example [here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html) was very useful. When the image quality is poor, there is some confusion as to where the template may lie and so four regions of interest (ROI), N, S, E, and W are selected from the original image and templates are matched within these regions.

For those interested, I chose a random selection of images from the image set and extracted my templates from this set. I then decide where the cutting edge was based on a majority vote between the templates in each region.